# Does Node.js actually use multiple threads underneath?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, posix

After all the literature i've read on node.js I still come back to the question, does node.js itself make use of multiple threads under the hood? I think the answer is yes because if we use the simple asynch file read example something has to be doing the work to read the file but if the main event loop of node is not processing this work than that must mean there should be a POSIX thread running somewhere that takes care of the file reading and then upon completion places the call back in the event loop to be executed. So when we say Node.js runs in one thread do we actually mean that the event loop of node.js is only one thread? Or am i missing something here.....

Comment: As far as I understood it I/O completion ports and the appropriate concepts on other platforms do not rely on threads, but something more light-weight built into the OS. But I was never sure if I understood this correctly ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To a Javascript program on node.js, *there is only one thread*.

If you're looking for technicalities, node.js is free to use threads to solve asynchronous I/O if the underlying operating system requires it.

The important thing is to never break the "there is only one thread" abstraction to the Javascript program. If there are more threads, all they can do is queue up work for the main thread in the Javascript program, they can never execute any Javascript code themselves.

Comment: Do you know more details about the "if the underlying operating system requires it"?

Comment: @GoloRoden Most operating systems have async I/O calls that don't require you to create any threads to use them, they use a callback mechanism/completion ports themselves. That said, I remember that Solaris used to create its own threads and do sync I/O on them "hidden" inside the async calls. The point was there too, the calling code had *no idea* if there were threads or not.

Comment: Okay, this means: If the operating system provides thread-less async I/O Node.js only requires one thread ever - if not, there may may be more threads required. Right?

Comment: @GoloRoden I think I was being a bit vague in my answer as to the point of causing confusion, sorry about that. As far as the _user_ of node.js (ie the Javascript programmer) is involved, *the abstraction is that there is only a single thread*. In the case of the underlying runtime (v8), it uses threads internally for - for example - profiling, and it may do so freely as long as it doesn't leak that information up to the Javascript. In other words, if you dive down inside the actual runtime, you will find more than one thread helping to keep the single Javascript thread running smoothly.